# Java - How do you read binary objects into an object array without knowing the size?

Tags: arrays, object

Java - How do you read binary objects into an object array without knowing the size beforehand? For example, I don't know how many "clients" are within a binary file so how do I read them into an array without knowing the size beforehand? I know I could probably use vector but I have to use an array.

Comment: hmm...I've been thinking about this but does dividing the total size of the file divided by the size of the objects give you the number of objects within the file?

Comment: Why 'have to'? Is this homework?

Comment: Well, I don't have to use an array. I can and know how to use a vector, I just want to know how to do it with an array of unknown size.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I just realized I don't really need to know the size. Doh!

ex.
objArray = ( SomeClass[] )inputStream.readObject();

Comment: Oh, dear, I wondered if that was at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an ArrayList, it creates a T[] of the reserved size.

When you add one too many items, it makes a new, larger T[] and uses System.arraycopy to move the contents.

For an unbounded number of possible inputs, this is the best you can do. You can even read the source of ArrayList to watch it being done.

Another possible solution applies when you can guarantee a maximum possible size, even if you don't know what the actual size is. You make an array as big as the maximum, put things into it. When done, create the final array of the actual size, and copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new array when you run out of space, then use [arraycopy](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to copy the old elements to the new.

Answer (score -3):

Use something from the collections library, like a vector or an ArrayList.

Comment: My answer is pretty much the same as the one that was upvoted, why am i being voted down?

Comment: bmargulies didn't recommend /using/ ArrayList.  He explained the internal implementation so the OP could replicate it.

Comment: How does that equate to me needing to read the question? Its also quite clear that while bmargulies explained how ArrayLists work, he was also advocating their use.